(Re)attaching to an App Insights Operation from another machine/process (not using HTTP)
I have a .NET 8 distributed system in AKS where work is divided among workers using a Manager/Worker pattern. With work shared out on a Redis List. I'm aiming to get unified logging via Application Insights, but I'm facing an issue. I can't currently pass important details like SpanId, TraceId, or ParentId unless it's through HTTP calls. How can I extract these details from the ILogger instance or some other part of the system, like a thread or a Task so I can pass them via messages on the Redis list?
The workers are using TPL Dataflow. When I receive a request on the worker, I want to continue the Operation started on the master. I believe the context data should transfer smoothly from there.
I can see the data I need in the logger but I'm struggling to access it.  The place where I need to access this stuff is deeply buried below the place where the operation is created, so I can't get it from the App Insights SDK itself (I assume?!?).

This screen-grab is a view of the Scope property of the ILogger instance.  I can see the data in the instance via my debugger, but I cannot get at it programmatically.
The ILogger instance and AppInsights are set up using dependency injection.  These are the relevant commands I used:
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddLoggingEtc(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.AddLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddSimpleConsole(options =>
            {
                options.IncludeScopes = true;
                options.SingleLine = true;
                options.TimestampFormat = "hh:mm:ss ";
            }).SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
            logging.AddLogLevelFilters();
            logging.AddApplicationInsights(
                configureTelemetryConfiguration: (config) =>
                    config.ConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"),
                    configureApplicationInsightsLoggerOptions: (options) => { }
            );
        });
        return services;
    }


To clearify, you are looking for a way to get the current SpanId inside a method that does not have access to an ILogger instance or the AI SDK?

Yes, that's right. But, I do have access to the ILogger, I just can't work out how to get the spanid etc out of it.

Which object is shown above? Would it be possible to add this to the question? Is there a way to come up with the smallest repro/example which illustrates a problem in isolation?

I've updated the question accordingly.  The relevant bits of setup I used are provided.  The skeleton of the app would be too large to include here.  And I am not permitted to share code anyway :).
